# Python Reportlab cómo dar formato a numeración

Tags: python, reportlab

Cómo añadir caracteres a los valores de numeración en reportlab desde python ejemplos:
 1. Este es el primer elementos
 2. Este es el segundo elemento

Otro tipo podría ser:
 a) Primer inciso
 b) Segundo inciso

No encuentro cómo añadir ".", ")", "-", etc.

```
Myitems.append(ListFlowable([  
                            ListItem(Paragraph("text", styleLeft),  
                            leftIndent=20)],   
                            bulletType='a', leftIndent=20, start=1))
```

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask]. Edita la pregunta y agrega algún ejemplo de código de lo que has intentado para que la pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Saludos.

Comment: Para obtener una mejor y más rápida respuesta podrías comentar qué estás haciendo con Reportlab a grandes rasgos, para tener una idea general y luego explicar un poco más el problema o duda puntual que tenes.

Comment: Sólo quiero crear un PDF, he puesto sólo lo que quiero hacer, una lista ordenada de elementos, pero que después del valor tenga un caracter.